# Configure SAX XML parser to avoid SAXParseException

Tags: xml, special-characters, sax, apache-commons-httpclient, saxparseexception

I am making a SOAP service call using [commons http-client](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) and getting the following exception -

> Exception processing message: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 20; col 
>   umnNumber: 23; An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x{2}) was found in the value 
>   of attribute "{1}" and element is "1".

I know I have a character

> ☺

in my data which is not allowed as per [XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets).

Is there a way to configure commons http-client/SAX XML Parser to ignore/remove/clean unsupported characters from the input data?

Comment: Can you paste some example xml to test? Which libraries are you using?

Comment: @tomaj I have updated the question to include more information

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the real problem is that your document contains a character that XML doesn't allow. Your problem is that the character isn't encoded the way that the file says it is, so the parser thinks it is a different character. Stripping out the offending character (which you could do with a preprocessing phase, e.g. using perl) might relieve the symptoms but it won't cure the disease. You need to work out what the actual encoding of the file is, and what the XML parser thinks it is, and why.

Comment: I am not sure how I can control the encoding of the file in my scenario. Could you please provide more pointers on the same?

Comment: Not easily, no. I've no idea how much you already know about the subject, and I don't know enough about the structure of your application to know what information might be relevant.